# How does generic type in declaration really affects the method if it's never used?

Tags: java, generics, htmlunit

I'm looking through HTMLUnit sources and can't quite figure out how is generic type supposed to work here. It's never used inside the method, what's the point of making the method generic?

```
public <T> List<T> getByXPath(final String xpathExpr) {
        PrefixResolver prefixResolver = null;
        if (hasFeature(XPATH_SELECTION_NAMESPACES)) {
            /*
             * See if the document has the SelectionNamespaces property defined.  If so, then
             * create a PrefixResolver that resolves the defined namespaces.
             */
            final Document doc = getOwnerDocument();
            if (doc instanceof XmlPage) {
                final ScriptableObject scriptable = ((XmlPage) doc).getScriptableObject();
                if (ScriptableObject.hasProperty(scriptable, "getProperty")) {
                    final Object selectionNS =
                            ScriptableObject.callMethod(scriptable, "getProperty", new Object[]{"SelectionNamespaces"});
                    if (selectionNS != null && !selectionNS.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        final Map<String, String> namespaces = parseSelectionNamespaces(selectionNS.toString());
                        if (namespaces != null) {
                            prefixResolver = new PrefixResolver() {
                                @Override
                                public String getBaseIdentifier() {
                                    return namespaces.get("");
                                }

                                @Override
                                public String getNamespaceForPrefix(final String prefix) {
                                    return namespaces.get(prefix);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public String getNamespaceForPrefix(final String prefix, final Node node) {
                                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean handlesNullPrefixes() {
                                    return false;
                                }
                            };
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return XPathUtils.getByXPath(this, xpathExpr, prefixResolver);
    }
```

Comment: This is the kind of code that ought to look pretty suspicious in Java: populating a list when the type of the list is entirely up to the caller. And indeed, [`XPathUtils.getByXPath` is using unchecked casts to populate the list](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/htmlunit/src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/xpath/XPathUtils.java#l69). Basically they're just expecting you to assign the result to the right kind of list, and if you don't, well, I hope you like debugging. They should really have you pass in a `Class<T>` to this method. It would be safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generics here are used to [infer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) the type `T` into the `XPathUtils.getByXPath` method, which signature is

```
public static <T> List<T> getByXPath(DomNode node, String xpathExpr, PrefixResolver resolver)
```

When compiler looks at this statement

```
return XPathUtils.getByXPath(this, xpathExpr, prefixResolver);
```

it infers the `T` type from the outer `getByXPath` method, which in turn infers `T` from its invocation.

So if you call `List<HtmlDivision> list = page.getByXPath(expr);` then `HtmlDivision` will be inferred into `getByXPath` and then into `XPathUtils.getByXPath`

Answer (score 1):

It's used for the return type (`List<T>`), so the returned `List` will have that specific generic type. This also means that `XPathUtils.getByXPath(…)` returns a `List<T>`, since that's what it's returning at the bottom of the method, so it's used inside the method there.

Comment: The question is still valid. It seems that generics is reduntant in this particular case. The only possibility is that `this` object is a generic somehow

Comment: It's not redundant, since otherwise the return value will only have type `List`, and code that expects `List<Whatever>` from that method will cause a compile-time error because `List` isn't `List<Whatever>`.

Comment: Then indeed it should be declared as `List<Whatever> getByXPath(String)`.